# RDF-Development Tools like Protege?

Tags: rdf, ontology, semantic-web, protege, rdfs

I`m quiet new to the whole semantic web topic. My main goal is to create an own vocabulary like schema.org. It provides it´s data via RDFa, a serialization-Format for RDF. So I searched for some RDF-Development Tools like Protege for OWL, but I poorly found any. Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create ontologies with the [Cameo Concept Modeler Plug-In](https://www.nomagic.com/product-addons/magicdraw-addons/cameo-concept-modeler-plugin) of [Magic Draw](https://www.nomagic.com/products/magicdraw).

There is also [PoolParty](https://www.poolparty.biz/).

I'm also aware of [Gra.fo](https://gra.fo/faq/).

With all these tools, you can create ontologies and export them in various formats.

Answer (score -1):

Apache jena, mobi, xmp,etc.
Try w3 tools

`https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/Tools`

Comment: Jena can help creating ontolgies programmatically, but I think the OP asked for a tool with a user interface, no ?